# default-scheduler 0/5 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had taints that the pod didn't tolerate, 4 node(s) had volume node affinity conflict

Tags: kubernetes, devops

Please could someone kindly advise me what the issue is:

> Warning  FailedScheduling  78s (x31 over 40m)  default-scheduler  0/5 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had taints that the pod didn't tolerate, 4 node(s) had volume node affinity conflict and my node and ebs volume are in same aws zone.

My nodes are in pending status.

Comment: Your pods might be in pending state , not nodes I hope. Just check if this answer helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51946393/kubernetes-pod-warning-1-nodes-had-volume-node-affinity-conflict

Comment: Your persistent volumes have a selector that doesn't match any of the nodes

Comment: Your persistent volumes have a selector that doesn't match any of the nodes ---why we need selector for node it is for pod right ? some pods default scheduler  o worker nodes but some pod in which pvc attached they are not move to worker node , when i m trying to delete pod and again create pod it is in pending status

Comment: Does your Pod spec contains any nodeAffinity ? if yes, change this pods’ node affinity requirements from hard to soft (requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution => preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution), should help in your case.