# After resizing the node in kuberentes : node(s) had volume node affinity conflict

Tags: kubernetes

I have a node pool that has only one node then I tried to upsize it to two nodes that I got the error :1 node(s) had volume node affinity conflict.(I'm using AKS)

I tried to also downsize to return it back to one node but the error remained.

I throughlu read this articl with people having same issues but for different cuase [Kubernetes Pod Warning: 1 node(s) had volume node affinity conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51946393/kubernetes-pod-warning-1-nodes-had-volume-node-affinity-conflict)

I understnad that this conflict might be becuase the pvc is secduling on different zones.

I tried to invstigate the issue, and I see that the failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io is not preesnt there

```
kubectl describe node aks-agentpool-10306775-0


Name:               aks-agentpool-10306775-0
Roles:              agent
Labels:             agentpool=agentpool
                    beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    kubernetes.azure.com/agentpool=agentpool
                    kubernetes.azure.com/cluster=[cluster name]
                    kubernetes.azure.com/mode=system
                    kubernetes.azure.com/role=agent
                    kubernetes.azure.com/storageprofile=managed
                    kubernetes.azure.com/storagetier=Premium_LRS
                    kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    kubernetes.io/hostname=aks-agentpool-10306775-0
                    kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    kubernetes.io/role=agent
                    node-role.kubernetes.io/agent=
                    node.kubernetes.io/instance-type=Standard_DS2_v2
                    storageprofile=managed
                    storagetier=Premium_LRS
                    topology.disk.csi.azure.com/zone=
                    topology.kubernetes.io/region=uksouth
                    topology.kubernetes.io/zone=1
```

I'm not sure that it should be there to be honest.. most of the answer in the referred article is due to have different zones. but for me I only have one node, one zone, one pv and one pvc.

When I dsecribe the pv i can see the zone and failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io

```
kubectl get pv


NAME                                       CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM                STORAGECLASS      REASON   AGE
pvc-4d65941a-3226-4078-a544-85dec3efe68a   128Gi      RWO            Delete           Bound    default/mssql-data   managed-premium            2y93d`
```

This is the description

```
kubectl describe pv pvc-aa4c6841-daee-4d36-bedc-f678704d73f8


Name:              pvc-aa4c6841-daee-4d36-bedc-f678704d73f8
Labels:            failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region=uksouth
```

Would you please advise ?

I'm tring to find the cause of the issue of my problem and how to slove it

The storage class:

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: azure-disk
provisioner: kubernetes.io/azure-disk
parameters:
  storageaccounttype: Standard_LRS
  kind: Managed
---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: mssql-data
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: managed
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 8Gi
```

I'm trying to find the issue of the problem and how to solve it

Please not that the issue started after I upgraded the k8 to 1.26.3 from 1.25.x

[UK GPA Calculator](https://do-calculate.com/calculator/en/gradetouk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the issue is that you have upgraded the node size for the cluster that contains databases e.g., SQL. your cluster uses the avlaialbit set, so you need to do it via the Availity set and don't try it use the Virtual Machine Scalability Set Otherwise, it will leave the cluster in an unsupported state e.g., node affinity conflict

To solve this, you need to give Azure some time to find the region of your cluster.

Comment: it worked long time ago, but yes you alright. i waited for some time  then it worked.